# Are AMQP connections (RabbitMQ) between Cloundfoundry applications possible?

Tags: jms, rabbitmq, cloud-foundry

I have two applications deployed on Cloudfoundry: a service application that computes stuff (aka computeService) and a client application that renders html for us mortals to hit buttons on (aka clientService). I would like a controller in the clientService to send commands to the computeService (when mortals hit buttons). The broker and the computeService run on the same machine.

I know I cannot make remote AMQP connections into a service on cloudfoundry.com, but I assume I can make connections between applications. However, every sensible address combination for broker and clientService gives me the same error:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://127.0.0.1:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Whatever address I try, I cannot post to the queue. The code works flawlessly on my local machine.

**My question**: can I use RabbitMQ to pass messages between the two applications on Cloudfoundry? And if so, which addresses should I use?

Thanx!

Comment: Have you reviewed: http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20322602-Getting-Started-with-the-RabbitMQ-Service-from-a-Spring-Application

Comment: @eightyoctane: thank you, I reread it. It seems I conflated JMS with AMQP.

Answer (score 1):

One way to try this out is to create two replicas of the rabbit message example at [Spring Samples](https://github.com/SpringSource/cloudfoundry-samples)

...a message sender and a message receiver. When deployed, they should share the same rabbit service.

I pushed the rabbit message which worked for me to: [rabbitmessage-sndrcv](https://github.com/eightyoctane/rabbitmessage-sndrcv)